# MySQL count(*) not returning rows with same input

Tags: php, mysql

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing with this one, spent atleast 1 hour looking for people with the same issue but couldn't find anything that would suit me / fix my issue.

```
$auth_user = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$asd = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket_replies WHERE uid=:userid");
$asd->execute(array(':userid'=>$user_id));
$rows = $asd->fetchAll();
$numrows = count($rows);
echo $numrows;
```

Not even sure if this is correct, but it does return 1 on the page.

```
$auth_user = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$asd = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT uid, count(*) FROM ticket_replies WHERE uid=:uname");
$asd->execute(array(':uname'=>$user_id));
$ticketsrow = $asd->fetchAll();
$count = count($ticketsrow);
foreach($ticketsrow as $row9){
  echo $row9['uid'];
}
```

The code above returns the value of '5' which is one if the values in the table, but obviously I wish for it to return in the 1, 2 & 3 orderly fashion.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.
[image: table]

Comment: Are you counting the COUNT result?  It should just return 1 row then.

Comment: Show some sample date and your expected result.

Comment: @Danieboy Goal at the end of the day is to count all rows, numbered. 6 rows, "6" on the page.

Comment: give a name of the count variable. It will be easy to you access.

Comment: Do you expect 6 individual records with count column?

Comment: @Tamil I want to return the number of individual rows with the same id. Say for example there is a forum post with replies on it and it says on the top right or something like 10 replies. I just want to know how to retrieve the number of rows with the same value of "uid".

Comment: Can you post a sample input and expected output in your question?

Comment: try groupBy user_id and count(*).. i think it will solve your problem...

Comment: @Jaimin the column is named uid though

Comment: ohh i missed that try groupBy on uid..

Comment: @Jaimin in the previous sql statement I had group by, should've stated that sorry. still returns '1', only reading one row

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ticket_replies WHERE uid=:userid" returns 6, right? If it does. It returns 6 in one row.   $numrows = count($rows);  Then counts the rows (1) and returns that. Because the "6" is still just one row returned from the SQL-statement.

Comment: @Danieboy I've updated the original post with a picture of the table as I'd find that easier to read, note the UID column. There are two fives and a ten. What I want to do is retrieve that information and display the (5's) as (2) as in two rows that have the value five. 

I would like for the (10) row to have the value of (1) since there is only one of them.

Surely this is possible, just doesn't seem like an easy task. It returns 1 at the moment and I'm not exactly sure why, the only reason I could think of is that it might be only reading the first row. One time it also returned 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove uid from where..

just apply groupBy on uid, i don't know the syntax but in simple sql statement it would be like

```
SELECT *,count(*) AS count FROM `ticket_replies` group By `uid` order by `count`
```

remove this also

```
$numrows = count($rows);
```

do this

```
foreach($ticketsrow as $row9){
  echo $row9['uid'];
  echo $row9['count'];
}
```

and you are good to go...

Answer (score 1):

Lets fix the issues with your first code block do the following

```
$auth_user = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$asd = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM ticket_replies WHERE uid=:userid");
$asd->execute(array(':userid'=>$user_id));
$rows = $asd->fetchAll();
```

`fetchAll` function retuns an array so when you use `count($rows)` what you get is the size of the array and not the result of the sql statement. To obtain the result of the sql statement you need to do the follow

```
print_r($rows)
echo $rows[0]['count']; // print the result of the sql
```

To fix the problem with your second code block do the following

```
$auth_user = new USER();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

$asd = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM ticket_replies GROUP BY `uid` ORDER BY `count`");
$asd->execute();
$ticketsrow = $asd->fetchAll();
print_r($ticketsrow);

foreach($ticketsrow as $row){
  echo $row['uid'];
  echo $row['count']
}
```

Comment: Your solution is also working for me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the count from the below query

```
select count(*) as count from FROM ticket_replies WHERE uid=:uname
```

Modify your code something like this

```
echo $ticketsrow[0]['count'];
```

The above query will always return exactly one row since you are passing userid in the where clause. Or just try to var_dump($ticketsrow) to get clue how to access count.